# Upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 15.10

How can be performed upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10? Is it enough to replace "trusty" as "wily" in sources.list and then run sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade?

Comment: You can't upgrade from 14.04 to 15.10 directly. Please **do not edit your sources.list**. If you can it would be better to wait until Ubuntu 16.04 was released in April. This will offer you a direct upgrade path from 14.04, as both are LTS releases.

Comment: Seriously, do a fresh install. No headaches. And wait for 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can not skip normal Ubuntu releases. You can upgrade one version at a time, which means you have to through 14.04 to 14.10 then 15.04 and finally 15.10. Alternatively you can upgrade LTS to LTS. which means you can wait for 16.04 and upgrade directly from 14.04 to 16.04. Modifying sources.list **wont help at all**.