# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade - Conflicting information

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, 15.10

I keep reading conflicting information about upgrading from 14.04 to 15.10. [This post here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/618741/update-ubuntu-14-04-to-15-04) suggests that in order to upgrade to 15.10, I first need to upgrade to 14.10 and then 15.04 before 15.10, and skipping upgrades in between is generally a *bad idea*.

That's all well and good, but when I try to follow the instructions in the post, I get this when running `do-release-upgrade -d`:

```
Err Upgrade tool signature                                                     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]                                        
Err Upgrade tool                                                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.200 80]                                        
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                      
WARNING:root:file 'utopic.tar.gz.gpg' missing
Failed to fetch
Fetching the upgrade failed. There may be a network problem.
```

There is definitely no problem with the network.

If I run the GUI `Software Updater` (after having changed `release-upgrades` from `lts` to `normal`), it suggests skipping right to 15.10!

On top of this, I then read the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/736245/upgrade-from-ubuntu-14-04-to-15-10) that I can actually skip directly between LTS versions. I don't mind waiting for 16.04 LTS if I need to, but I'd prefer to do the incremental upgrades if its going to result in a more reliable system.

Could someone please explain the truth to me here? Because these seem contradictory.

EDIT: I tested the same steps on another machine also running 14.04 LTS, and the `do-release-upgrade -d` command worked, however it tried to upgrade directly to 15.10 and completely broke the system (wouldn't boot). So it seems like going directly to 15.10 is still a terrible idea. So what is the alternative upgrade path? Do I need to reinstall from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LTS to LTS is an officially supported upgrade path. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes Considering 16.04 comes out soon, your best bet is to wait for that.

Answer (score 0):

> Upgrade from 14.04 or 15.10 to 16.04
>   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XenialUpgrades

## Short version

Do:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

instead of

```
do-release-upgrade -d
```

## More resources with possible arising problems

- Have a good /etc/apt/sources.list [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)
- The update scripts doesnt upgrade the kernel which is a bug [Ubuntu kernel not updating with 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689358/ubuntu-kernel-not-updating-with-15-10)